# A question regarding a step in power method justification (Writing a vector in terms of the eigenvectors of a matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a $t \times t$ matrix. Can we present any $t \times 1$ vector, as a linear combination of eigenvectors of $A$?
I think this should not be the case unless all eigenvectors of $A$ happened to be linearly independent. (right?) 
But it seems to be used in the proof of power method below.

Edit:
That is how the argument works: Suppose $x_0$ is an initial vector. Write it in terms of eigenvectors of $A$, i.e. $x_0 = \sum_i c_i v_i$ where $v_i$ is the $i^{th}$ eigenvector and $\lambda_i$ the corresponding eigenvalue. Let $x(n) = A^n x_0$.  We want to find $\lim_{n \to \infty} x(n).$ Based on the first assumption we have $x(n) = A^n \sum_i  c_iv_i= \sum_i c_i \lambda_i ^n v_i= \lambda_1^n \sum_i (\lambda_i/\lambda_1)^n v_i$  where $(\lambda_1, v_1)$ is the leading eigenpair.  Since $\lambda_i/\lambda_1 <1, \forall i\neq1$, all terms in the sum decay exponentially as $n$ becomes large and hence in the limit we get $x(n) = c_1 \lambda_1^n v_1$. In other words, $x= \lim_{n \to \infty} x(n)$ is simply proportional to the leading eigenvector of the matrix.  Equivalently,  $Ax = \lambda_1 x$.

Comment: The eigenvectors of a matrix form a spanning set if and only if the matrix is diagonalizable.

Comment: eigenvectors with distinct eigenvalues are always linearly independent

Comment: "the proof of the power method" Which proof? In which book/paper/website/t-shirt?

Comment: I updated my question with an argument about why power method works, that in my understanding implicitly uses the claim I asked about.

Comment: If you want to have any comments on "the proof of the power method", you should include a precise statement of what is being proved. So that we can better show why the purported proof is not correct and what additional hypotheses would be neceery to make something of it. For starters, $\lim{n\to\infty}x(n)$ does not exist (the limit diverges) unless you are in a _very special_ case, so there is no point in reasoning about it.

Answer (score 0):

As @oldrinb already said, eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are always linearly independent.

Next, a matrix has a basis of eigenvectors if and only if it's diagonalisable, which is not always the case, consider $$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$
This matrix has only one eigenvector (up to a constant factor) $\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$.

Another issue arises when you want to have diagonalisability over $\Bbb R$, not $\Bbb C$. For example, a matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$$ is diagonalisable over $\Bbb C$ and not diagonalisabe over $\Bbb R$.

So finally, any vector is a linear combination of eigenvectos $\iff$ there is a basis of eigenvectors $\iff$ the matrix is diagonalisable.

Your illustration with power method is not really relevant. It makes many assumptions on the matrix (in most cases we ask it to have real eigenvalues and the eigenvalue of the biggest absolute value to be of multiplicity one).

Comment: Thanks. (My main goal is to understand the mentioned argument about power method.) And I do not think there is an assumption that the matrix is diagonalizable in power method, is it?

Comment: Indeed, you can make this method work for non-diagonalisable matrices. Yet you need an aausmption that the leading eigenvalue is unique and of multiplcity one. Wiki article on power method gives the proof. Note that in that case you can't talk about basis of eigenvectors, only a basis of generalised eigenvectors.